# c++ linker error LNK2005 already defined in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, linker-errors

I am compiling my program using VS2005. I am linking to SDL static libraries and am getting the following linker errors;

```
1>LIBCMTD.lib(fpinit.obj) : error LNK2005: __fltused already defined in SDL2d.lib(SDL_stdlib.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(ftol2.obj) : error LNK2005: __ftol2_sse already defined in SDL2d.lib(SDL_stdlib.obj)
1>   Creating library ..\..\..\product\VS2005\libs\\Standalone.lib and object ..\..\..\product\VS2005\libs\\Standalone.exp
1>..\..\..\product\VS2005\libs\\Standalone.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I compiled SDL2d.lib using the same VS2005 compiler. My original thought was that I had mismatched runtime library settings for these projects. However after checking they are both set to Multi-Threaded Debug.

I have just noticed that the linker output above seems to be creating a Standalone.lib and Standalone.exp before making the Standalone.exe. I have no idea why it's making a .lib and .exp

Any other reasons why this error would occur?

Thanks

Comment: This means you are using more than 1 runtime. It seems here you are mixing Debug and Release in the same application. `LIBCMTD.lib` is part of the debug CRT. `LIBCMT.lib` is part of the release CRT. If you are building a Debug application make sure not to use Release libs and viseversa.

Comment: *"However after checking they are both set to Multi-Threaded Debug."* That cannot possibly be correct. And if it is, you're linking to another library that you didn't mention in the question. The linker errors very clearly indicate that the conflicting library is `LIBCMT`, which is the release version.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my quote was wrong. Ive edited the question and replaced LIBCMT.lib with LIBCMTD.lib. The linker output doesn't mention LIBCMT.lib, just somehow went missing during my copy and paste. My apologies, question edited

Comment: The edit only fixed it in one place. The output also says: `defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs`...

Comment: Ive fixed the LIBCMT issue and you were correct. The linker now doesnt report the different versions. However it still doesnt correct the original question. Post edited to remove the LIBCMT issue in linker output

Comment: You are still clearly trying to link object files targeting two different versions of the CRT. One or more of your project settings have to be incorrect, or there have to be additional libraries involved that you aren't telling us about (and haven't rebuilt). There isn't enough information here to provide any further help. This isn't a bug in Visual Studio; I've successfully compiled and linked many projects in VS 2005.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Needed to define HAVE_LIBC in the SDL project. This stopped the multiple redefinition of both _ftlused and _ftol2_sse

Comment: It is defined by default in the SDL headers. This should not be necessary unless you previously edited them to remove the definition.

Comment: `SDL_config_winrt.h` does define `HAVE_LIBC`... but I wonder how many people use that? ;) SDL 2.04 and SDL 2.05 don't otherwise seem to set it, for whatever reason. But when using cmake, you can specify `-DLIBC=ON` on the cmake command line to create a SDL_config.h that has `#define HAVE_LIBC 1` in it. This was only an issue with the x86 build for me.